# mysql_num_rows doesn't work when there are no rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

First off, yes, I know `mysql_num_rows()` is deprecated.

Now, continuing on to the actual question, I'm making a page where users can post things and other users can like them. But when the post displays, and the user viewing them didn't/hasn't liked the post, the `mysql_num_rows()` doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
<?
$plikes=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM postLikes WHERE username='$myusername' AND postId='$postId'");
$plikesRows=mysql_num_rows($plikes)or die("error: ".mysql_error());
if ($plikesRows>=1) {
//stuff
}
else {
//other stuff
}
?>
```

the variables `$myusername` and `$postId` are set correctly, and I tested the query and it works without any errors. But when I go onto the page, all it displays is a "error:", without any error.

Comment: if you know it's deprecated, why are you continuing to use? If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: It's because I'm working with an older system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of code is not doing what you think it is. `mysql_num_rows($plikes)` becomes `0` which is type juggled to `false` so the second half of the `OR` statement is triggered. This happens because by using `OR` you turned the results of line of code into a boolean evaluation.

```
$plikes=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM postLikes WHERE username='$myusername' AND postId='$postId'");
if (!mysql_error()) {
    $plikesRows=mysql_num_rows($plikes);
    if ($plikesRows>=1) {
    //stuff
    }
    else {
    //other stuff
    }
}
else {
    die("error: ".mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Although its fine but try to use mysqli_ functions because as you know that mysql_ is deprecated